# how to make Scamblesuit+openvpn work?

Tags: obfsproxy, openvpn

I ran into this error when I tried to use Scamblesuit+openvpn.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 586, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 199, in doRead
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obfsproxy-0.2.7-py2.7.egg/obfsproxy/network/socks5.py", line 162, in dataReceived
    self.processAuthentication()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obfsproxy-0.2.7-py2.7.egg/obfsproxy/network/socks5.py", line 234, in processAuthentication
    self.AUTH_METHOD_VTABLE[self.authMethod](self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obfsproxy-0.2.7-py2.7.egg/obfsproxy/network/socks5.py", line 131, in <lambda>
    (lambda self: self.processNoAuthRequired()),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obfsproxy-0.2.7-py2.7.egg/obfsproxy/network/socks5.py", line 320, in processNoAuthRequired
    self.processRequest()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obfsproxy-0.2.7-py2.7.egg/obfsproxy/network/socks5.py", line 380, in processRequest
    port = msg.get_uint16(True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obfsproxy-0.2.7-py2.7.egg/obfsproxy/network/socks5.py", line 507, in get_uint16
    ret = struct.unpack("!H", self[0:2])[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
2014-03-24 19:48:54,053 [DEBUG] socks_up_0xdabc30: Connection was lost (unpack requires a string argument of length 2).
2014-03-24 19:48:54,055 [DEBUG] socks_up_0xdabc30: Closing connection.
```

I think the length of `self[0:2]` is 2. Can anyone shed some light on this, thanks.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Could you please add your OpenVPN configuration file?

Comment: This isn't a ScrambleSuit issue since it's choking in the SOCKS5 code (before ScrambleSuit enters the picture).  I would need to see a hexdump of the SOCKS5 traffic to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an obfsproxy bug on systems running Python < 2.7.4.

You could try the branch linked off the [tor trac entry](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/11329) associated with this problem or wait till obfsproxy 0.2.8.